# Is this byte array a password-protected PDF document?

Tags: c#, pdf, detection, password-protection

I have a C# byte array, and I need to know if it's a password-protected PDF document.  How can I make this determination?

I'm inspecting the document for the PDF magic cookie to determine if it's a PDF document, but I don't know what's best when determining if it's password protected.

I don't need to open the document (though, as long as there's no UI required -- this is a background process, I'm OK with doing that if it helps).

I just need to know if there's a password on this PDF document.

**EDIT:** If you cite iTextSharp, I'd be very grateful if you'd cite a specific resource within that API that addresses this concern.

Comment: the question is pretty vague... there are two types of "passwords" possible on a PDF... user and master.. there could be just a master passowrd... depending on the "rights" set it could be that a user doesn't need a passowrd but for example isn't allowed to print the document... so what exactly you want to find out in that byte stream ?

Comment: I want to know if there is either of two password types on the document: user or owner ("master", as you've called it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities for password-protecting PDF, some defined by Adobe ("standard") and as part of the standard it is possible to have so-called "alternate security handlers".

Anyway all can be detected basically by checking for the respective "dictionaries" as described on pages 115 - 136 of the PDF spec - see http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

Comment: This wasn't light reading, but it gave us the information we needed to determine what we needed to determine.

Answer (score 2):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can be used to perform such check.

The library provides different methods to check if bytes, stream or file contain a password protected PDF document.

Please take a look at the article that shows [how to check if an existing PDF document is password protected](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/passwords/decrypt#check-pdf-protected).

Disclaimer: I work for the company.

Comment: Glad you plugged your API here.  This looks like a much easier option than what we've done.